# TV show where a mole on a picture frame turned out to be coded information

Tags: story-identification

The show was about spies or detectives or something similar, a man and a woman who were partners. The woman's parents had disappeared a long time ago and she had a picture frame to remember them by. But the beauty mark/mole on her parent's face in the picture turned out to be a fake that she could remove and when expanded (I believe by water) it contained intel on the parents.

I think it was a cartoon, probably aired in 90s or early 2000s.

Comment: What a bizarre concept! Hope we find it!